# how to compare date / timestamp in laravel while querying the mode?

Tags: datetime, laravel, laravel-4, php-carbon

I have a data something like this `2014-12-30 09:07:49` assigned to created_at.

I have a number, 12 as a parameter value. What I want to do is, I want to compare number, 12 with the above created_at and target to the month. How would I do that.

What I have found is, Laravel automatically convert these created_at to Carbon Object during retrieval of data. Is there a way just to extract month part of created_at during the retrieval?

```
        public function filterUser($month){
            $user = User::where('created_at', $month)->get();
        }
```

Obviously, the above code does not work. I found doing `CarbonObject->month` would get the month from the timestamp/Carbon object. But how would I implement this idea for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a raw expression in combination with the [`MONTH()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) function.

```
$users = User::where(DB::raw('MONTH(created_at)'), $month)->get();
```

(`DB::raw` allows you to use SQL functions, otherwise they would get escaped)